# Do I need to add a MixRGB node for all of my decals in order for their colors to be changed in a 3D configurator?

Tags: export, shaders, color

I am preparing a blender model for a 3D configurator, which I have never done before, and I need the logos to be able to change color with certain color changes to the main surfaces of the model. Do I need to add a MixRBG node to all of them with the other color I want or can I take care of all of that in the configurator?

I have two wraps and all logos need to change between pink and white/orange. Right now I have a mixRBG node for the wraps and logos, using a property driver to change between the two.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: I think the details of this lie in the configurator, it's in your best interest to do some testing to see what you can do, if you don't have any documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'm thinking I might just be able to take care of it in the configurator. At least for the surfaces, not sure about decals though.

Comment: My question is: Do I need to add mixRBG nodes to everything I want to have color options in my configurator? (including decals) Or does the configurator have the ability to differentiate all of my layers and define/change their colors?